# When two polynomials $f(x),g(x)$ over a field $F$ are said to be relatively prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra

When two polynomials $f(x),g(x)$ over a field $F$ are said to be relatively prime?

- Following the definition given for the integers I guess when two of them have no factors in common other than $1.$ But if we follow such definition it implies $-1$ and $x+1$ are not relatively prime.

My second question is when does $f,g$ are relatively prime provided one of them is $0?$

Comment: A sensible definition is that $f$ and $g$ are relatively prime if the ideal $(f,g)$ is all of $F[X]$. This takes care of your two special cases.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Does the definition of the "relatively prime" given in an UFD (i.e. $a_1,...,a_n$ in a UFD $R$ is called relatively prime if every common divisor is a unit) applicable here?

Comment: Note that even in the case where the (commutative) ring, the definition that Mariano gives still makes sense (even if the ring does not have nice divisibility properties). By the way, any polynomial ring over a field is a UFD. In fact if $R$ is a UFD so is $R[x]$.

Comment: @BabyDragon: What does "nice divisibility properties" mean?

Comment: The ring may not have unique factorizations. The ring, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ is not a UFD. I would call being a UFD a "nice divisibility property". Another "nice divisibility property" might be being a Dedekind domain. My point was that the ring may not have any nice properties whatsoever (other than units and possibly commutative, but I am sure that people work with these as well) in order for the definition to make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant property here is that any field is a [GCD domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCD_domain), which means that any two nonzero elements have a GCD (ordered by divisibility).  And once $F$ is a GCD domain, $F[x]$ is as well.  "Relatively prime" means that their GCD is 1 (up to units, of course).

In this context $\gcd(-1,x+1)=1$, up to units; so in some sense $F\setminus \{0\}$ is the gcd.  Also for nonzero $\alpha$, $\gcd(\alpha,0)=\gcd(\alpha,\alpha)=\alpha$, again up to units.

Comment: This is a nice answer. I have not heard of GCD domains.

Comment: A personal question regarding a doubt: why do we define gcd for nonzero's even when all the elements are divisor of zero (including $0$ itself)? Of course if both of them are zero we can't calculate the gcd but when one is nonzero (and the other is $0$) doesn't the non-zero element become the gcd?

Comment: @Sriti, please see the last sentence; I edited it.